# Merge different rows to one and count how many rows were merged

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

Let's say I have the following rows in my table:

```
ExternalID   Count   Descriptor
   1           1        val-1
   1           1        val-2
   2           1        val-3
   2           1        val-4
   2           1        val-5
   2           1        val-6
   3           1        val-7
```

I would need to accomplish something like this:

```
ExternalID   Count       Descriptor
   1           2        val-1, val-2
   2           3        val-3, val-4, val-5
   3           1        val-7
```

Would something like this be possible?

Comment: Please make helping you eaiser. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible but perhaps not the done thing/best utilisation of the available features of relational databases.

This very much appears to be a case for utilising the advtanges of relationships.

How about considering a table for External Id's and a table for Descriptors and then a link table (assocciative table or the many other names uses for tables that tie relationships).

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE externals (_id PRIMARY INTEGER KEY, extid INTEGER)
CREATE TABLE descriptors (_id PRIMARY INTEGER KEY, descriptor TEXT)
CREATE TABLE link_externals_to_descriptors (external_ref INTEGER NOT NULL, descriptor_ref INTEGER NOT NULL)
```

So for the above you have (*note I've used id's 10-12 and 100-106 just to distinguish them easily for illustration purposes*):-

**Externals Table**

```
 _id       extid

 10        1
 11        2
 12        3
 99        9
```

**Descriptors Table**

```
_id        descriptor
100        val-1
101        val-2
102        val-3
103        val-4
104        val-5
105        val-6
106        val-7
```

**Link table** (link_externals_to_descriptors)

```
external_ref         descriptor_ref
1                    100
1                    101
2                    102
2                    103
2                    104
3                    106
99                   100
99                   102
99                   104
99                   105
99                   107
```

This may seem and may be overly complex but copes with one-many, many-one and also many-many relationships between externalID's and descriptors.

i.e. **99** would be the equivalent to

```
9                   val-1, val-3, val-5, val-6, val-7
```

*(all except val-6 being used by others)*

There would be no need to merge or to un-merge, split the csv into individual descriptors. You just get what you want. e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM link_externals_to_descriptors WHERE external_ref = 99;
```

being used to drive a query would return a cursor who's count (number of rows) would be the number of descriptors for the external id.

As such, the following could be used to get the count and the descriptors (outputting the info to the log) :-

```
Cursor csr = db.query("link_externals_to_descriptors",
    null,
    "external_ref=?",
    new String[]{"99"},
    null,null,null);
int my_count_of_descriptors = csr.getCount()
Log.d("MYINFO","The number of Descriptors for EXTID 99 is" +
    Integer.toString(my_count_of_descriptors) +
    " They are:-");
while(csr.moveToNext) {
    Log.d("MYINFO","\t" + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("descriptor_ref")));
}
csr.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

To get one output row per group when querying, use GROUP BY, and use [aggregation functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) to merge values:

```
SELECT ExternalID,
       COUNT(*),
       group_concat(Descriptor)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY ExternalID;
```

If the original `Count` values matter, replace `COUNT(*)` with `SUM(Count)`.